# include link list depending on category

Tags: wordpress

I want to display the linklist widget only on a certain category.

The current way the sidebar is fetched is:

```
if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar(1))
```

Which doesnt give me a say in the calling of the links widget. If i put an if clause there, then the rest of the widgets dont get loaded.

So i either need to customize the links widget it self or find a way to call the links widget directly?

And how do i check which category i'm on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call an indivdual widget by using [Conditional Tags « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), like this:

```
<?php if (in_category('1')) { ?>  call widget here
<?php } ?>
```

Or (haven't used this myself) load widgets by category, etc: [WordPress › Dynamic Widgets « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-widgets/)

Answer (score 0):

To print the Category you are on use the_category(' ');
Example :`<p>Categories: <?php the_category(' '); ?></p>`
Also have a look at the Documentation http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_category